# Remove a character from java string using hex code

Tags: java, regex, hex

i would like to remove a character from java string using hex code:

i am trying following code but seems to not be correct as the character isn't replaced: ÿ

```
String str ="test  ÿ";
str.replaceAll("\\x{9F}","")
```

is there any thing wrong with the syntax of the hex code? Thanks.

Comment: ÿ isn't in ASCII to start with. That character is [U+00FF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ff/index.htm) - I'm not sure why you'd expect that regular expression to match it. The fact that you don't use the return value of `replaceAll` doesn't help either.

Comment: have you tested in any tool whether \\x{9F} would actually match that symbol?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: Why don't you just use `str.replaceAll("ÿ","");`? Shouldn't that work?

Comment: @khelwood easier to use replace compared to replaceAll? no

Comment: `\x{9F}` is a PCRE way of defining Unicode code points in the regex pattern. In Java, use `\uXXXX` notation. And just `str = str.replace("ÿ","")` will work, too.

Comment: @Stultuske Why not? Why should this problem require a regular expression?

Comment: Following up on Jon Skeet's comment, simply assign `str.replaceAll("\\x{00FF}","")` to your replacement `String` if you need to use hex values and `replaceAll`, which you might not.

Comment: @JonSkeet i editted my question, i meant hex value, for the return i posted only the revelant code.

Comment: @Meryem That's not what Jon meant. Return of `replaceAll` is the only relevant thing, because Java strings are immutable. You need to do `str = str.replaceAll(...)` in order for it to have any effect on `str`.

Comment: @khelwood you are missing my point. I wasn't talking about the regex, I was talking about  replace / replaceAll, that's all. yes, it expects a regex, but when applied with just a regular String, it'll give the same result as a list of replace statements.

Comment: As a side note: I would not mix the actual character in the string with hex-encoded escape values, since how the code works is then dependent on what the java compiler uses as encoding for the source file, which may be depending on the environment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is what i was using at the begginning bu usint the ant build tool it failed to map that character that's why i tried to swith to hex value.

Comment: @Meryem: So use a hex value *in a Java string literal* rather than going via regular expressions for no reason: `str = str.replace("\u00ff", "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mach ÿ you need \u00ff instead, as Jon mentioned.

```
String replaced = str.replace("\u00ff", "");
```

in your case.

Comment: I'd use `replace` rather than `replaceAll` here, as it's conceptually simple - just replacing a string rather than a regex pattern.

Comment: i'll try this and give a feedback

Comment: The double-escape of the \ is wrong, isn't it? Ok, not wrong with replaceAll, but unnecessary...

Comment: Jon replace is sufficient in this case, you are right. Ctx yes, and it is wrong with replace, so it's better just have it as \u as you say. Changed it as you suggested, it's better this way.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this:

```
    public class AsciiHexCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String  str = "test  ÿ";
        String result = str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
        System.out.println("result : "+ result);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, can you please tell what is the \\x00-\\x7F range for? thank you.

Comment: That is range of hexcode of ascii, you can see here - http://www.addressmunger.com/hex_ascii_tables/